# How to load specific firefox profile using robotframework and Selenium libraries

Tags: selenium, robotframework, firefox-profile

I am trying to automate few tasks related to a website and I would like to load Firefox profile (where I have specific settings done) using Selenium libraries in Robot Framework.

I have written below (which doesn't contain all the steps) -

```
*** Setting ***  
Library    SeleniumLibrary
Library    AutoItLibrary   
Library    Process 

*** Variable ***
${url}=    MY URL HERE
${ff}=    C://Program Files//Mozilla Firefox

***Test Case***    
Load FF profile
   Create WebDriver    Firefox    firefox_profile=${ff}
   Go To    ${url}
```

The above code loads Firefox browser, but doesn't load the Firefox profile I am looking for. How can i tell wedriver to launch specific Firefox profile? I have looked at various settings in '**Create WebDriver**' method from Selenium Library and all those setting didn't help me.

I am able to launch required Firefox profile using AutoIT code below -

```
$FF = @ProgramFilesDir & "\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
Run($ff)
```

Answer (score 0):

The profile path you give to `Create Webdriver` looks like the install directory of FF - at least in the example above. It must be the full path to a *profile* dir.

If it still doesn't work for you, try with the [`Open Browser` keyword](http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Open%20Browser) - it's more high-level, and has the argument `ff_profile_dir` for exactly this usage.

---

The autoit code works for you, as it just starts the FF binary, and in doing so the browser starts with the default (your normal one) profile. When Selenium starts a browser instance, it creates a brand new profile - so it's not "polluted" with your settings, extensions, etc - if not overridden through those parameters in the keywords.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
Start_Firefox
    [Arguments]    ${URL}
    ${FF_PROFILE}=    Set Variable    C:\\Your\\path\\to\\profile\\here\\FFprofile
    Open Browser    ${URL}     browser=ff    ff_profile_dir=${FF_PROFILE}
```